# longest string array segmentation fault

Tags: c

Write a C function `longestStrInAr()` that takes in an array of strings `str` and `size` (>0) as
parameters, and returns the longest string and also the length of the longest string via the
pointer parameter length. If two or more strings have the same longest string length, then the
first appeared string will be returned to the calling function. For example, if `size` is `5` and the
array of strings is `{ "peter", "john", "mary", "jane", "kenny"}`, then the longest string is `"peter"` and
the string length is `5` will be returned to the calling function

I am getting a segmentation fault here and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 20

char *longestStrInAr(char str[N][40], int size, int *length);

int main() {
    int i, size, length;   
    char str[N][40], first[40], last[40], *p, *result;
    char dummychar;   
    
    printf("Enter array size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    scanf("%c", &dummychar);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter string %d: \n", i + 1);
        fgets(str[i], 40, stdin);
        if (p = strchr(str[i], '\n'))
            *p = '\0';   
    }  
    result = longestStrInAr(str, size, &length);
    printf("longest: %s \nlength: %d\n", result, length);         
    return 0;
}

char *longestStrInAr(char str[N][40], int size, int *length) {
    char *p;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int j = 0; int max = 0, *length = 0;
        while (str[i][j++] != '\0') {
            max++;
        }
        if (max > *length) {
            *length = max;
            p = str[i];
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: When you ran it under a debugger, which line faulted'

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```c
int j = 0; int max = 0, *length = 0;
```

is bad. A new pointer variable `length` is declared here and initialized to `NULL`, shadowing the argument `length`.
After that, this `length` (`NULL`) is dereferenced and it will cause Segmentation Fault.

To initialize what is pointed at by the argument `length` to zero, the line should be:

```c
int j = 0, max = 0; *length = 0;
```

Comment: I don't think that it is good programming style to have a statement on the same line as a declaration.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I agree. I also think that the better place for `*length = 0;` may be *before* the `for` loop.

Comment: "To initialize what is pointed at by the argument length to zero, the line should be:" -- This sentence gives the impression that you are recommending to put a statement on the same line as a declaration. You may want to elaborate a bit in your answer.

Comment: took me a long time to see the difference between those 2 lines. split them up

Answer (score 1):

In function `longestStrInAr`, the code in the `for` loop is incorrect:

```
    int j = 0; int max = 0, *length = 0;
```

defines 3 local variables: `j`, `max` and `length` as a new pointer to `int`, initialized as a null pointer. This `length` variable has the same name as the function argument but is defined in the scope of the block that is the body of the `for` statement, hence it *shadows* the argument with the same name. This problem would have been diagnosed by the compiler if given a higher level of warnings (**gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow**, **clang -Weverything**).

This is causing the segmentation fault: when you later dereference this pointer in `if (max > *length)`, you have undefined behavior  as `length` is a null pointer.

You probably meant to just use the argument and initialize `*length`, and you should do this **before** the `for` loop. Note also that you should initialize `p` as `p = str[0]` for the pathological case where all strings are empty for which the posted code returns an uninitialized pointer. As a matter of fact, there is another special case to consider: if `size` is `0`, the function should return `NULL`.

There are some problems in the `main` function too: if `size` is greater than `N`, you read strings beyond the end of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 20

char *longestStrInAr(char str[][40], int size, int *length);

int flush_input(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int i, size, length;   
    char str[N][40];
    char *result;
    
    printf("Enter array size: \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 0 || size > N) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // read and discard the rest of the input line
    flush_input();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter string %d: \n", i + 1);
        str[i][0] = '\0';
        scanf("%39[^\n]", str[i]);
        flush_input();
    }  
    result = longestStrInAr(str, size, &length);
    printf("longest: %s \nlength: %d\n",
           result ? result : "(null)", length);         
    return 0;
}

char *longestStrInAr(char str[][40], int size, int *length) {
    char *p = NULL;
    *length = 0;
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            while (str[i][j] != '\0')
                j++;
            if (*length < j) {
                *length = j;
                p = str[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: I agree, answer updated.